# Оптимизация алгоритма на Python

Tags: python

Задача из олимпиады, я не понимаю, как можно оптимизировать свой код. Текст задачи ниже:

> Магистр Йода известен тем, что использует необычный порядок слов. Эта
> особенность имеет еще одно следствие. Когда магистр называет какое-то
> расстояние, площадь или объем, он использует множество приставок
> системы Си. Каждая приставка системы Си умножает единицу измерения на
> некоторую степень десяти. Например, он может сказать
> «megananokilogigamicrometer», что будет соответствовать 10^3 метрам.
> Если речь идет об объёме, то он может сказать «millimeter^3», что
> будет соответствовать 10^9 метрам кубическим. Например, если Йода
> сказал «megananokilogigamicrometer», то это равно
> 10^6+10^(-9)+10^3+10^9+10^(−6) метрам или 10^3 метрам. Правила применения
> приставок к квадратным и кубическим величинам также являются
> стандартными. Например, один кубический метр равен 10^6 кубическим
> сантиметрам.

> К сожалению, C-3PO рядом не оказалось, и вам нужно
> самостоятельно расшифровать, что именно сказал Йода. Переведите
> единицу измерения, которую назвал Йода, в метры, метры квадратные или
> метры кубические, в зависимости от разрядности исходной единицы
> измерения. Несложно показать, что у вас получится величина, равная 10x
> (метров, метров квадратных или метров кубических), где x — целое
> число. Выведите x.

Я написал код, который перебирает приставки в слове и поочередно удаляет их. Можно ли этот код оптимизировать, если это вообще возможно. Заранее благодарю

```
words = {'tera':12, 'giga':9, 'mega':6, 'kilo':3, 'deci':-1,'centi':-2, 'milli':-3, 'micro':-6, 'nano':-9}
result = 0
test = input()

##ИЗБАВИЛСЯ ОТ СТЕПЕНЕЙ
if '^' not in test:
    m = 1
if '2' in test:
    m = 2
    test = test.replace('^2', '', 1)
if '3' in test:
    m = 3
    test = test.replace('^3', '', 1)

##ПЕРЕБОР ПРИСТАВОК
while test != 'meter':
    for key in words:
        if key in test:
            result += words[key]
            test = test.replace(key, '', 1)
            
print(result*m)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in words:
    result += words[key] * test.count(key)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно решило все